# How many bytes are received with dataReceived?

Tags: python, twisted

I am using Twisted to receive data from a socket.
My protocol class inherits from Protocol.

As there are no byte type in Python 2.*, the type of received data is str.
Of course, len (data) gives me the length of the string but how can I know
the number of bytes received ? There is not sizeof or something equivalent that allows
me to know the number of bytes ? 
Or should I consider that whatever the platform, the number of bytes will be 2 * len (data) ?

thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you assume `2*len(data)` and not `1*len(data)`?

Comment: because I thought that a char was coded over two bytes. If it is not the case, it is perfect for me

Comment: The whole point of 2.x str/3.x bytes is that it's a collection of bytes. The number of bytes is always len(data). With 2.x unicode/3.x str, it's a collection of characters; whether those are 2 bytes, 4, sometimes-2-sometimes-4, or something else is irrelevant because there's no way to directly access the bytes anyway.

Comment: PS, there is a bytes type in (later versions of) 2.x; it's just a synonym for str, but it exists, and works pretty much the same as the bytes in 3.x.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python 2,

- `str` → a sequence of bytes, which is sometimes used as ASCII text
- `bytes` → an alias for `str` (available in python 2.6 and later)
- `unicode` → a sequence of unicode code units (UCS-2 or UCS-4, depending on compile time options, UCS-2 by default)

In Python 3,

- `str` → a sequence of unicode code units (UCS-4)
- `bytes` → a sequence of bytes
- `unicode` → no such thing any more, you mean `str`

Think of the type passed to `dataReceived` as `bytes`.  It is `bytes` in Python 2.x, it will be `bytes` when Twisted has been ported to Python 3.x.

Therefore, the length in bytes of the received segment is simply `len(data)`.

Answer (score 4):

The length of the string is the length in bytes.